# When finding a diagonal matrix of a linear map does it matter which way we order the eigenvalues down the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we wish to find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $D=P^{-1}AP$ where

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-10 &18 \\ 
 -6&11 
\end{pmatrix}$$

When we find the eigenvalues of the matrix we get $2,-1$ my question is this does it matter whether we take $$D=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 &0 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{pmatrix}$$ or $$D=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0&-2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

then when you want to find $P$ you find a basis for each eigenspace and then just let $P$ be the matrix with the elements of each basis for the two eigenspaces as the columns for $P$, does the order in which you place these column vectors matter as well?

Will it give the same matrices whichever order? Is some orders wrong? Or does it just give different matrices with the property we desire?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the columns of $P$ will correspond to the order of the diagonals in $D$. The first column of $P$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $D_{11}$, the second column corresponds to $D_{22}$, and so on. If you reorder the elements on the diagonal of $D$, you have to reorder the columns of $P$ in the same way so that $P^{-1}AP=D$ is still true.